# How to get Azure Service Fabric Linux VM metrics to Application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, azure-virtual-machine, azure-linux

I'm interested in tips how to get few critical VM system metrics (CPU, memory) into Application Insights. The VMs are nodes of Azure Service Fabric cluster. OS is Unbuntu 16.04 x64. The deployed application is written in C# .NET Core.

It can be done quite easily by marriage of [Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/PerfCtrs/performance-counters-portal) and [Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow), however that's **Windows**, so I'm looking for **similar solution on Linux**.

So far I didn't find any and I'd be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Based on this doc, it appears logging on Linux clusters does work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-overview

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Logging is not an issue. I'm looking for a way how to get system metrics into Application Insights.

Comment: Either in similar fashion as on Windows clusters (Performance Counters + EventFlow) or maybe some trick how to get them from Azure tables. I mean other than writing some custom application shoveling records from Azure tables through TelemetryClient to AI.